# Please help, my program is not accepting MySQL floats

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I have to use a java program . I need to understand it and then modify it. The program has a source folder. It has a lot of java files. the program has a GUI interface. i have imported the program in eclipse and i can run the program. i want to learn and understand the code but since its too big i want to only read the relevant portions of the code which i need to understand to modify / add features to the program. This program requires input data . this data can be in a CSV file or a MySql database. the immediate problem i am facing with the program is that i need to use float data as input data in one of the columns. when i put data in decimal form in the CSV file . the program has no problem in accepting it and processing it. but when i create a MYSQL database table with floating datatype as one of the column . the program while importing data gives error - "unknown data type float . add this entry is xxx.props file " even after i add the float entry in xxx.props file in the proper way just as other entries are there for other data types in xxx.props file, i still get the same error . what should i do next ? which part of the code should i study to find out the problem?

Comment: please provide more context, some fragments of code, explain what is the xxx.props file and any exception the program throws...

Comment: This might help you help us help you http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Does the program execution gives you any StackTrace. Maybe it could help you to analyze the problem easier and better

Answer (score 1):

When you say it "gives error" - does it throw an exception? If so, find out where that exception is thrown from, and work backwards from there.

You haven't explained what the xxx.props file is, how you created the mysql table, or what you're then doing with it, which makes it kinda hard to give any more specific help...

Answer (score 0):

Without a direct question, I can't help you much. However, I can advise you on how to solve the problem.

1. Learn the basics before you try to make a leap to do everything at once. Try to learn these before coming everything:

   1. Get a working knowledge of Java
   2. Figure out how to develop a GUI that isn't binded to your logic. (Take a look at the MVC design pattern)
   3. Break up the big program into manageable parts
   4. Implement your logic separately from your data access (M C part of MVC)
   5. Use Unit Testing to verify that your components work
   6. Implement the CSV reading, and then move it to the database

This way you have seperable components that will make your job easier to deal with, and you will learn quite a bit along the way.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of small questions but I think your main question is "why am I getting this 'unknown data type float' error".  Without looking at any code my first suggestion would be to validate how you're inserting/updating the MySQL table.  Hopefully the developer extrapolated the data tier from the UI tier meaning there should only be one or two java classes to look at to verify how the data is inserted.

Overall, it sounds like you're new to Java and application design.  Try to follow how the program works from point A to point B.  Hopefully the code was broken out into tiers to make it easier for you;  IE the GUI is in it's own package/project and the business logic is in it's own package/project, so on and so on.